# How to handle GET and POST needs different numbers of argument in web.py framework

Tags: python, web.py

When develop an restful style API server with web.py micro framework .  i have an issue about multiple URL with a handle class and http method funcation needs defferent arguments. for example：

```
URL：
url =['/api/users', 'User',
        '/api/users/(\d+)$, 'User']

Class:
class User(object):
    def GET(self, id=None):
         Pass

    def POST(self):
        Pass
```

Issues:
When use postman call /api/uses/1 with POST method
Will happen an exception. How to fix it?

Comment: Make the `POST` method's signature the same as the `GET` method's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in a comment, make POST method's signature the same as GET:

```
def POST(self, id=None):
   ...
```

Your issue is due to the fact that your POST request `/api/users/1` includes the final ID. That means `webpy` matches the pattern `/api/users/(\d+)$`, which is then handled by `class User`. If you GET that url, it goes to `<User>.GET()`, if you POST that url, it goes to `<Users>.POST()`... (`DELETE` goes to `<User>.DELETE()`, etc.)

Because the matching pattern includes a regex capture `(\d+)`, that matched value will be passed as an additional argument to the function.... whichever function is called.

You can use a non-capturing regex: `(?:\d+)$` which will require a match in the URL, but will not cause the matching value to be passed as a argument, so:

```
url = ('/api/users', 'User',
       '/api/users/(?:\d+)$', 'User')

class User(object):
    def GET(self, id=None):
        pass
    def POST(self):
        pass
```

Now, `/api/users` and `/api/users/1` will go to `User` class, and get handled by GET or POST depending on the request. Note that because you're no longer capturing the `id` your `GET(self, id=None):` still works, but will **always** have None for the id (because it's not captured!)

Most likely, what you want is the simple: make the arguments the same.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use flexible number of arguments:

```
def GET(*arg):
    self = arg[0]
    id = arg[1]
```